# div ngIf if the firestore collection does not return any document

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm working with AngularFire2, what I'm basically trying to do is show a div if the function does not return any document from a certain collection, that is zero. If you return a document or more this div should disappear.

I have tried the following but without the expected results:

**service.ts**

```js
size: number;
contadorSize;

contadorEventosPropios() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    this.contadorSize  = this.afs
        .collection('eventos', ref => ref.where('autorId', '==', user.uid))
        .get().subscribe(snap => {
          this.size = snap.size;
          console.log(this.size);
        });
    return this.contadorSize;
}
```

**component.ts**

```js
size: boolean;
contadorSize: number;

constructor( public fs: FirebaseService, private afs: AngularFirestore ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.contadorSize = this.fs.contadorEventosPropios();

    if (this.contadorSize === 0 ) {
        return this.size = true;
    } else {
       return this.size = false;
    }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="size">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: invert this.size = true/false with return statement. Like: this.size = true; return;

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I tried but the div is still not showing even though the function returns 0

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the `Subscription` object. You could change it to something like:

**service.ts**

```js
size: number;
contadorSize;

contadorEventosPropios(): Observable<number> {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    this.contadorSize  = this.afs
        .collection('eventos', ref => ref.where('autorId', '==', user.uid))
        .get()
        .map(snap => { // instead of subscribe
          this.size = snap.size;
          console.log(this.size);
          return snap.size;
        });

    return this.contadorSize;
}
```

**component.ts**

```js
size: boolean;
// contadorSize: number; // wrong
contadorSize: Observable<number>; // corrected

constructor( public fs: FirebaseService, private afs: AngularFirestore ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.contadorSize = this.fs.contadorEventosPropios();
    // removed
}
```

**component.html** ([async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) can do the trick)

```html
<div *ngIf="(contradorSize | async) === 0">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: That worked well, although with some small modifications. When I added the `.map` it threw me an error: `The property 'map' does not exist in the type 'Observable <QuerySnapshot>'. Ts` then I had to wrap it in an `.pipe` Then in the component.ts I had to assign `counterSize: any`. With this I managed to work but I have to update to detect the change.

Comment: What is the `counterSize`? Is it the same thing as `contadorSize`? I've also noticed one thing wrong in my answer. In component.ts contadorSize should be of the `Observable<number>` type

Comment: I've edited the answer (changed the type of `contadorSize`). Does using it with the `async` in the tamplate require to "update to detect the change"?

Comment: `counterSize` is the same as `contadorSize` sorry for the translation. The use of `async` if you need to update the page to detect the change. Is there a way to achieve it without being updated? The same is not bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling your async calls properly. It's a good idea to add types to all of your variables so it's easier to see the intent and where you're going wrong.

Try changing your service to something like:

```
contadorEventosPropios(): Observable<{ size: number; }> {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    return this.afs
        .collection('eventos', ref => ref.where('autorId', '==', user.uid))
        .get();
}
```

And your component to something like:

```
size: boolean;

constructor( public fs: FirebaseService, private afs: AngularFirestore ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.fs.contadorEventosPropios().subscribe(result => {
      if (result.size === 0 ) {
          this.size = true;
      } else {
         this.size = false;
      }
    });
```

Comment: [@Stanley De Boer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2022667/stanley-de-boer) `result` is not a number. It still won't work. Result is an object which contains the `size` property

Comment: @kasptom Thank you for pointing that out. Does it look better now?

Comment: [@Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2022667/stanley-de-boer) yes. I would also remove the `return` keywords from the if / else clause